# How to call a foreach loop from a PHP function and output results in HTML

Tags: php, html

Good day!

I have written a *function getData()* that is running a query to SELECT all data from my database.

```
    function getData() {

     try {

       $pdo = new PDO("mysql:host=localhost;dbname=db", 'root', '');
       $pdo->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);

       $sql = "SELECT * FROM table";
       $stmt = $pdo->prepare($sql);
       $stmt->execute();

       foreach ($stmt as $row)
       {
         echo $row['username'];
       }

    } catch(PDOException $e) {

    echo "Connection failed: " . $e->getMessage();

    }
```

To output the data, I do a foreach loop and echo the results. No brainer, this situation works for me outside the HTML that I want to output the results in.

But, I hope to output the results inside a HTML table:

```
 <tbody>
  <tr>
   <?php getData();
     foreach ($stmt as $row) { ?>
       <td>
         <?php echo $row['username']; ?>
       </td>
   <?php } ?>
  </tr>
 </body>
```

Is there something in my code that I am missing? Am I not following a correct procedure? I hope to learn from this to better improve in the coming future and I hope I did my best to ask the question to help understand my situation.

Thank you!

Comment: Does it seem to be working? I'm guessing not. What are the problems you're facing? What have you done to debug this? Is `$stmt` iterable with `foreach`? Do you get table rows if you only loop `<td>` tags?

Comment: Move the HTML loop into the getData replacing this `foreach ($stmt as $row) { echo $row['username']; }` Otherwise your getData has to RETURN an array or some other iterable. Unless  your  $stmt is global in scope in your PHP

Comment: I think it is good to iterate over `$stmt->fetchAll(\PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)` instead of `$stmt`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of `echo`'ing in `getData()`, you should add each result to an array and return that:

```php
function getData() {
  ....
  $results = array();
  foreach ($stmt as $row) {
     $results[] = $row; //add each result to the array
  }
    
  return $results; //return the data
}
```

Then in your HTML assign the result of `getData();` to a variable:

```
$data = getData();
```

And then loop on the $data variable:

```
foreach ($data as $row) { ?>
<td>
    <?php echo $row['username']; ?>
</td>
<?php } ?>
```

Comment: If only I could give this answer or you 100000 rep! Thank you so much for this! **For anyone that is coming in to this question, the answer is right here!**